# Eclipse: InvocationTargetException after adding (object instanceof Class newObject)

Tags: java, eclipse

When I want to use:

```
if (!(object instanceof Class newObject)) {
```

I can't use F3 or hover on something, error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$26(ProgressManager.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.SelectionConverter.performForkedCodeResolve(SelectionConverter.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.SelectionConverter.codeResolveForked(SelectionConverter.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1084)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1107)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmKeyDown(Widget.java:1792)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_KEYDOWN(Control.java:5162)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_KEYDOWN(Canvas.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4785)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4958)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3624)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1041)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Comment: Please show the error log starting with `!SESSION`. Is your Eclipse up to date? Please provide a [minimal example with which your issue can be reproduced in the current Eclipse without additional plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What "with !SESSION"?

Comment: Minimal example would be something like that:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            if (!(arg instanceof Object) object) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: I updated eclipse and so far it's not showing, thank you for help. :)

Comment: The bug is still there

Comment: When it's a bug, make sure it has been reported to Eclipse with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You can report Eclipse bugs [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)